# Sticky menu - how can I get an image to appear as soon as it "sticks"?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sticky menu bar that start sticking when one scrolls below the header where I placed my anchor.

It works well but I would like to have an image appear on its left side once it starts "sticking". I saw the same effect on newyorker.com.

How would I do that?

Here's my code that makes it stick:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
   var scroller_anchor = $(".scroller_anchor").offset().top;

   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'fixed')
   {    
      $('.scroller').css({
         'position': 'fixed',
         'top': '0px'
      });

      $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '50px');
   }
   else if ($(this).scrollTop() < scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'relative')
   {    

      $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '0px');

      $('.scroller').css({
        'position': 'relative'
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to add the image? Maybe link to some similar questions or articles you've worked off of. I'd also recommend including your HTML so we know how it all fits together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the **CSS** do this for you.. just add class `showed` to the image on 'sticking' and then remove it when not 'sticking'

### CSS

```
.home_image{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.home_image.showed{
    display: block;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
   var scroller_anchor = $(".scroller_anchor").offset().top;

   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'fixed')
   {    
      $('.scroller').css({
         'position': 'fixed',
         'top': '0px'
      });

      $('.home_image').addClass('showed');

      $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '50px');
   }
   else if ($(this).scrollTop() < scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'relative')
   {    

      $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '0px');

      $('.scroller').css({
        'position': 'relative'
      });

      $('.home_image.showed').removeClass('showed');
   }
});
```

---

Another way without adding classes:

## CSS

```
.home_image{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
   var scroller_anchor = $(".scroller_anchor").offset().top;

   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'fixed')
   {    
      $('.scroller').css({
         'position': 'fixed',
         'top': '0px'
      });

      $('.home_image').css({
        'display': 'block'
      });

      $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '50px');
   }
   else if ($(this).scrollTop() < scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'relative')
   {    

      $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '0px');

      $('.scroller').css({
        'position': 'relative'
      });

      $('.home_image').css({
        'display': 'none'
      });
   }
});
```